# Property [ID] Does not exist on this collection instance Laravel 9

Tags: php, mongodb, collections, laravel-9

Context: I am updating an old Laravel application from PHP 5 to PHP 8 and Laravel 6 to Laravel 9. DB being used is MongoDB, and my normal work is in MySQL, so I am not sure if this is simply an issue from one of the PHP/Laravel upgrades that I haven't been able to find online or if it is a Mongo issue. I did not write the original application, so many of the ways the previous developer wrote things are not how I would write them, but I am trying not to gut this app and start over completely.

In the constructor portion of a Class that is called to create Invoices, we get a collection of Printable Invoice data from our database. I get the error "Property [id] Does not exist on this collection instance" from this code:

```
if (!isset($invoice)){
  $invoice = Order_Invoice::with(array(
        'order',
        'services'=>function($query){$query->orderBy('entity_order')->orderBy('service_order');},
        'services.entity',
        'services.locations',
        'services.fees'=>function($query){$query->orderBy('sort_order');}
  ))->find($id);
}
$this->invoice = $invoice;
$this->id = $invoice->id;
```

When I do a "dd($invoice->id);" before the line that throws the error, the page dies, and I get a clear ID from our tables.

Is there something I might be missing that would cause the collection to throw an ID does not exist error?

I tried dd() on several different variables.
I reworked the above query to use a first() query instead of find since the ID is not always an integer, but that also threw its own errors.
I removed all the with joins to see if that was causing issues.

Comment: Your code is checking `if(!isset($invoice))`, at which time it creates a single `Order_Invoice` model Instance via `->find($id)`. However, if `$invoice` **is** set, it's probably a `Collection` of `Order_Invoice` models, so you'd have to do `$this->invoice = $invoice->first()`. Or, better yet, expand your `if()` to _also_ check if `$invoice` is a single Model instance instead of a `Collection`.

Comment: *"Is there something I might be missing that would cause the collection to throw an ID does not exist error?"* - Collections don't have an `->id` property, since (typically) it's a Collection of database records, and each item in the Collection has an `->id` property. `collect([(object)['id' => 1]])->id` (a Collection of a single Object with an `id`) triggers the error, while `collect([(object)['id' => 1]])->first()->id` correctly returns 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlGTn.png

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you for your response, I checked if either of these could be causing the issue.  To account for both of them, I simply added     $invoice = $invoice->first();
after my "if (!isset($invoice))" to make it one singular record whether the if is true or not.  Once again I dd($invoice) and see that I return a result, but now the error thrown is Attempt to read property "id" on null. If I dd($invoice->id), it returns a value

Comment: *"To account for both of them, I simply added $invoice = $invoice->first();"* - No, don't do that... The code after `if(!isset(...))` is always hit, and if you're doing `$invoice = Order_Invoice::with(...)->find($id); // ... $invoice = $invoice->first();`, you're gonna have a bad time... `->find()` returns a single Instance or `null`, and `null->first()` is not valid, and `(Order_Invoice Instance)->first()` pulls the first record from your database (since Models can be used to Query in Laravel too). You need to handle the specific cases of a Collection, a Single Instance and `null` separately.